# Shape of output change during TPU training Keras funcional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, kaggle, tpu

*ValueError: Mismatch between expected batch size and model output batch size. Output shape = (16, 6248), expected output shape = shape (1, 6248)*

I defined in the last dense layers of my model is (None, 6248)

I can't understandable what is the number 16 in this output. All of code without any number 16.

Desciption:
i'm use TPU V3 in kaggle for training. **but if i using GPU then i'm not get any Error when i make prediction "model.predict(...)"**.

I create model with Keras functional API

Please make me clearly. Thank!
Here is my model.

```py
    embedding_layer = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                                EMBEDDING_DIM,
                                weights=[embedding_matrix],
                                input_length= max_sequence_len - 1,
                                trainable=False)

    sequence_1_input = Input(shape=(max_sequence_len - 1,), dtype='int32')
    embedded_sequences_1 = embedding_layer(sequence_1_input)

    activations = Bidirectional(LSTM(num_lstm, dropout=rate_drop_lstm, recurrent_dropout=rate_drop_lstm, return_sequences=True))(embedded_sequences_1)
    activations = LSTM(num_lstm, dropout=rate_drop_lstm, recurrent_dropout=rate_drop_lstm)(activations)

    merged = Dense(num_dense, activation=act)(activations)
    merged = Dropout(rate_drop_dense)(merged)
    merged = BatchNormalization()(merged)

    preds = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(merged)


    model = Model(inputs=sequence_1_input, outputs=preds)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

Here is my data:

```py
train = predictors[0:10240]
test = label[0:10240]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train, test))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(200).batch(1024).repeat()
dataset = dataset.prefetch(AUTO)

#Here is the shape of dataset:

<PrefetchDataset shapes: ((None, 87), (None, 6248)), types: (tf.int32, tf.float32)>
```

Fit model:

```py
model.fit(dataset, epochs=100, steps_per_epoch=10240//1024, verbose=1)
```

Summary

[image]

Comment: 16 is your batch size. Or you are feeding the data wrong or the model does one full reduction somewhere instead of just a reduction on one of the axis. Do you have more code to show?

Comment: Thank for your response. i just added my code. Please show me my error. Thank

Answer (score 2):

Just want to mention that i get a similar error.

It makes me believe that there must be a bug in tensorflow.(also getting "16" as first output shape)

I already gave "batch_size" a "1" on the predict function just to make shure.

Sadly it has no impact at all.

Maybe it receives the batch of 16 from the tpu?

That could lead that self.results is unexpected at this location:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e5bf8de410005de06a7ff5393fafdf832ef1d4ad/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py#L346

But I'm currently clueless of how to fix it without patching tensorflow itself.

EDIT:

Thats damn difficult to debug ... currently i think the error is somewhere nearby this:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e5bf8de410005de06a7ff5393fafdf832ef1d4ad/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py#L262

Since it somehow handles the output shape based on "num_replicas_in_sync".

But can't realy figure it out without debugging.

Some Debuginfo with pdb:

```
(Pdb) b /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py:262
Breakpoint 7 at /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py:262
(Pdb) c
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py(262)_aggregate_predict_results()
-> nested_outs = batch_outs[i * num_replicas:i * num_replicas + num_replicas]
(Pdb) print(len(batch_outs))
8
(Pdb) print(batch_outs[0].shape)
(2, 7, 355, 235, 1)
```

The "2" is already wrong for me at the beginning, not shure why this is happening.(it later gets changed to 16, leading to "batch_outs" with multiple duplicates)

**Edit again (28.04.2020):**

The problem seems to happen earlier:

```
(Pdb) b /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py:128
Breakpoint 3 at /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py:128
(Pdb) c
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py(128)run_one_epoch()
-> batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
(Pdb) n
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py(159)run_one_epoch()
-> if mode != ModeKeys.PREDICT:
(Pdb) print(len(batch_outs))
16
(Pdb) print(batch_outs[14].shape)
(2, 7, 355, 235, 1)
(Pdb) np.array_equal(batch_outs[14],batch_outs[15])
True
```

**Edit again (29.04.2020):**

As a workaround alteast the following seems to work:

```
  from tensorflow.python.tpu import device_assignment as device_assignment_lib
  tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float32')
  tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()  # TPU detection
  tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
  topology = tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
  device_assignment = device_assignment_lib.DeviceAssignment(
          topology, core_assignment=device_assignment_lib.
          SINGLE_CORE_ASSIGNMENT)
  strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu,device_assignment)
```

Of course thats not the best fix, since that way you are only using one core.
Atleast it confirms my guess that tensorflow is not correctly filtering out the results from all cores.

Comment: Thank for your response. But when i convert "X" to datasets like this `X = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X)` then i make prediction like: `model.predict(X)` then i get the output of prediction is array which 16 elements. I don't understand how did work!

Comment: Well, I myself still can't figure out why its 16 and not 8. My guess is that it asks all cores for the prediction. And all answer with the same result, but somewhere in tensorflows backend the result gets sized up because it believes the result from every core is a new result. (alteast thats my guess)

Comment: for some background info: I'm using kaggle. But according to the info at https://www.kaggle.com/docs/tpu they should have 8 cores. (so the result of 16 for the first shape of the result is still confusing)

Comment: Basically the problem is, that you are having a batch-size of 1. Normaly they validate the InputLayer-batch-size(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e5bf8de410005de06a7ff5393fafdf832ef1d4ad/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_layer.py#L74), but because batch_size is None by default and they do not validate the real input shape for some reason, you are running into trouble.So I guess you are forced to create a second strategy(that uses a SINGLE_CORE_ASSINGMENT) and model just for prediction.Well either that you give it input with 1st sthape of "divisible by the number of replicas".

Comment: Thank for response, I think i got some idea. I'll try these.